# Почему не работает переопределения get{return "\(zc1)->\(zc)"}

Tags: swift, swift3, переменные, переопределение

Не судите строго, я новичок в программировании Swift, почему такое переопределения работает.

```
class A{
var b:String=""  
}

class C:A{
  var zc=2
  var zc1:String="Значения"
  override var b:String{
  set{ zc1=newValue}
  get{return "\(zc1)->\(zc)"}
  }
}

var uu=C()
print(znac.b)
```

А такой  код, не работает если мне к примеру хочется переопределить не строковую переменную именно числовую.

```
class A{
var b:Int=0
}

class C:A{
  var zc:Int=2
  var zc1:String="Значения"
  override var b:Int{
  set{ zc=newValue}
  get{return "\(zc1)->\(zc)"}
  }
}

var znac=C()
print(znac.b)
```

Hо выдает такую ошибку

```
Swift:: Error: cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 
'Int'
  get{return "\(zc1)->\(zc)"}
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Посмотрите внимательно переменная `b` у вас типа `Int` а вы возвращаете `return "\(zc1)->\(zc)"` тип `String`

А в первом случае вы возвращаете `String` как и должно быть.

Comment: Так и в первом  случае выводится и тип Int тоже вы водится, а здесь нет, если я хочу переопределить только числовое значения,  строковое оставить, оставить.

Comment: В первом случае выводиться String. "\(zc1)->\(zc)" - это строка просто вы Int выводите как String

Comment: Жаль  что, я вам не могу голосом рассказать и  показать, в чем проблема и как я хочу сделать( Hо я по другому решил сделать код, но мне это вариант слишком громоздкий кажется.   `class A{
 var a1:Int=0 
}

class C:A{
 var zc:Int=2 
override var a1:Int{
 set{zc=newValue} 
 get{ return zc}
 }
}

var znac1=C()
print("Значения=>\(znac1.a1)")`

Comment: Все правильно сделали. Код нормальный, не нужно бояться много кода нужно бояться непонятного кода.